# Chrome suddenly automatically opens PDF files in Adobe Acrobat after download

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Since a few weeks, after I've downloaded a PDF file, Chrome suddenly has started to open these files in Adobe Acrobat. I have absolutely no idea why that happens.

Does someone know what the reason for this bug could be?

Answer (score 0):

Killing Adobe Collaboration Synchronizer in Task Manager seems to fix the issue. Not sure how to stop this from launching at startup -- it's not listed in the Startup tab in Task Manager.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 setting for such a feature. Clearly the first is in Chromes setting where after download (as all PDFs have to be run local) you ask it be redirected into a browser.

[image]

Previously that could include Acrobat Plugins but in recent Chromiums except MS Edge that feature was removed.

[image]

However other features have bee added experimentally.
[image]

You can also optionally add Adobe PDF Chrome Extender.
[image]

MS Edge has the ability to use a "Powered by Adobe Acrobat" built in plugin.
[image]

Some browsers continue to embed Acrobat DC Reader.

[image]